# Text descenders are clipped for badge info

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, feed, ios-app-feed

The descenders are clipped in this line of text:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the 1.5.0.1.

I never set the label's `font`, just the font of the `attributedString` and I guess `TTTAttributedLabel`'s sizing logic didn't like that.